# Remote control API for Spotify?

Tags: spotify

Is there such a thing as a Spotify remote control API? I want to write an app which lets the user control the Spotify desktop client (play, pause, volume, playlists, etc.) but I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere.

There are iOS and Android remote control apps out there so I'm just wondering how they do it if there isn't an API.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X, Spotify can be controlled 'remotely' (i.e. from other apps) using AppleScript, either using the bundled API or the System Events service.

Here's an example of using the bundled API: https://github.com/activars/spotify-applescript/blob/master/spotify_control.applescript

And another one using System Events (it isn't quite as elegant): http://www.jacktams.net/2010/04/28/spotify-applescripts-version-0-4-3/

Official documentation is a bit thin, although you should be able to use the AppleScript editor's library feature to find out more about the methods offered.

Comment: If you go the System Events route of doing things, you can probably do pretty much anything the Spotify app can do, including creating and editing playlists. I wouldn't recommend that though as it's quite hackish (it's really just sending simulated keypresses to the app itself).

Comment: As for the bundled API, try the Script Editor's Library window.

Comment: what about M$ windows ? is there any approach ?

Comment: @alizx I don't know of any. You could try asking a new question, detailing what you're trying to do exactly.