# Controlling desktop Spotify player through API

Tags: spotify

I want to write a google chrome extension that allows the user to play/pause Spotify desktop player from their chrome.

Is there an API for this? A REST API that routes the request through Spotify servers to the desktop player may have a little delay but better than nothing.

Any ideas?

PS. I don't want to control the web player and [Remote control API for Spotify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337685/remote-control-api-for-spotify) this not my answer